# MvvmCross syntax to consume a service defined in a plugin and the lifetime of that service within the application

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a `LoginService` and its interface defined in an MvvmCross (Mvx) Plugin.

My Mvx Application's core PCL that consumes this plugin uses `App.cs` to register it like this:

```
        CreatableTypes(typeof(LoginService).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

It then uses a `CustomAppStart` class to startup the app to determine which ViewModel to start the app with:

```
RegisterAppStart(new CustomAppStart(Mvx.Resolve<ILoginService>()));
```

With CustomAppStart defined as:

```
        public CustomAppStart(ILoginService loginService)
        {
            _loginService = loginService;
        }

        public void Start(object hint = null)
        {
            if (!_loginService.IsLoggedIn)
            {
                ShowViewModel<LoginViewModel>();
            }
            else
            {
                ShowViewModel<HomeViewModel>();
            }
        }
```

Two part question:

1. Am I using the correct syntax with `CreatableTypes` and
   `RegisterAppStart` to use `LoginService` that is defined in the plugin?
2. I know that by using `RegisterAsLazySingleton()` I will get the SAME
   LoginService instance when I request it, but what is the lifetime of
   that instance?  Once I request it in CustomAppStart does the state
   of that instance just remain in memory for me to call on and use or
   does Mvx magically save and rehydrate its state when one of my
   ViewModels requests the same instance of ILoginService in its
   constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** The syntax you are using for `CreatableTypes` looks OK to me.

When not using it inside `App` then the documented syntax is:

"
And you can also, of course, use the same type of registration logic on assemblies other than Core - e.g.:

```
    typeof(Reusable.Helpers.MyHelper).Assembly.CreatableTypes()
        .EndingWith("Helper")
        .AsInterfaces()
        .RegisterAsDynamic();
```

"
from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control#bulk-registration-by-convention

`CreateableTypes()`, `EndingWith()`, etc are all just fairly short extension methods acting on `System.Type` - you can see them in [IoC/MvxTypeExtensions.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/IoC/MvxTypeExtensions.cs) - e.g.

```
    public static IEnumerable<Type> CreatableTypes(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        return assembly
            .ExceptionSafeGetTypes()
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)
            .Where(t => t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Any());
    }
```

---

**2.** The lifecycle of a singleton is that once created it stays in RAM as long as the Application does. The only way to remove it from RAM would be to remove all references to it - including removing the IoC container reference (which could only be done by registering a new implementation in its place).

Comment: Is there a way of doing this, without Core needing to know about the other assembly at the time of development.

Since the interfaces are in the Core assembly, I need to reference Core from my service assembly, which means that I cannot reference Services from Core, unless I create a new assembly, just for interfaces.