# MvvmCross services from another assembly, not MyApp.Core

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've got a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704224/mvvmcross-with-two-core-libraries). But the difference is that I have some services which code would want to share between several projects (different .Core projects).

As I see, dependency registered like:

```
          CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Services")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

does not get into the assemblies, which lie in 'third-party' assemblies.

However, how should I do that 'automatically' (in meaning, to use it in Touch and Droid the same simple way as .Core services (without additional code)), kind of

```
        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("GeneralService")
            .InNamespace("General.Core.Services")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

(which also does not work for me)?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MvvmCross syntax to consume a service defined in a plugin and the lifetime of that service within the application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470342/mvvmcross-syntax-to-consume-a-service-defined-in-a-plugin-and-the-lifetime-of-th)

Comment: Thanks, Stuart! That really did work with typeof(Reusable.Helpers.MyHelper).Assembly.CreatableTypes() ... That was a bit confusing when the service was mentioned 'defined in a plugin' in that link. I've also got the following related to defining general code in different asseblies question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497700/how-to-resolve-imvxapplication-which-inheritor-is-defined-in-separate-assembly. Thanks again!