# How to resolve IMvxApplication (which inheritor is defined in separate assembly (not Core one))?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, multiplatform

I have usual **MyApp.Core project**. However, I also have **General.Core project** which includes some *general code for apps and services shared through different projects* (different mobile applications).

In General.Core project I have:

```
public abstract class App : MvxApplication
```

and also some service defined also on General.Core.

I also have

```
  public abstract class SomethingApp : App
```

in MyApp.Core (and then in every of Touch, Droid - further inheritance).

However, when I try to get to my App from the service of General.Core project (the same as App) like that:

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxApplication>()
```

I get '**cannot resolve**' exception. I am sure that's because of types names and different assemlies, but I don't know what and how I should Register (if I should) the app, because it's not just a common service.

Thank you!

Comment: sorry - I don't understand this question. Could you expand it with why you want to resolve the app? This interface is something that MvvmCross calls internally - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/IMvxApplication.cs - you shouldn't be calling it yourself.

Comment: The reason why I would need that is because of the following: 
1. I try to utilize my code and create some base class of the app (as mentioned above in the question). 2. I need to have something like public virtual IEncryptionProvider CreateEncryptionProvider() method as I need it to be used then in EncryptionService (used by another services). I need that method, because I can not utilize Encryption for all the platforms together, so I need to override its creation for Touch and Android (but rather not for WP (default implementation (actually, that's also proper dll referencing))).

Comment: Not sure if that's fully correct architecture decision (if the app is considered to be obtained only internally (however, why I can not get it if I can override it?)), but this is what I came up with (for now).

Comment: Sorry - I've read this and the comments several times and still have no idea what you are doing. There are some good docs on the IoC implementation on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control and the N+1 N=31 video deals with platform specific services - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n31-injection-platform-specific.html - hopefully one of those two will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still need to play with my code a bit though.